# Free OpenGTS/GPS tracking service provider (to use with Android GPSLogger)

Tags: gps, service-provider, opengts

I am quite new to this topic. I found GPSLogger for Android. There I can set to log to a server. But I have no idea what destination service I could use.

I only want to send my position e.g. every minute to a server so that I can give someone access to my position.

Comment: Did you ever find a "destination service"?  I presume you wanted  to use the GPSLogger app to post your position "somewhere", so that you could tell people to go to a specific URL to see a map of where you are and where you've been.